# Mutual Exclusion using Redis

Tags: redis, synchronization, locking, mutual-exclusion

I [read about](http://redis.io/topics/distlock) Redis being used for mutual exclusion. [Docs](http://redis.io/topics/distlock) say the following :

[image]

Can somebody explain what condition can this simple implementation fail for achieving mutual exclusion.

For all the instance trying to do some critical work, do the following (pseudo code) :

```
while ( set keyForMutex anyValue nx == nil )
{
    sleep ( 200 ms )
}

Finish up the critical task.

del keyForMutex
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wouldn't fail in achieving mutual exclusion, but it could over-succeed and deliver infinite exclusive exclusion if your code dies before it gets to deleting the key.

A possible solution is to expire the key after a generous timeout to allow the critical task to end.